# Three.js : Update Segment color for a PlaneBufferGeometry,

Tags: three.js

How do I Update or have different colors for each segment in a planeBuffergeometry?

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5, 20, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xCC0000,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(plane);
```

What I'm trying to do is actually update each segment in the grid as a user clicks a part of the plane.

Comment: The easiest solution is to use `PlaneGeometry` instead and follow [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html), but use `WebGLRenderer`. You can use `PlaneBufferGeometry`, but doing so is more tedious in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work. I'm trying to update each segment of the planegeometry, so the planegeometry will have multiple colors.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gm7a42ax/